# autocomplete dynamic text boxes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm tryin to follow solutions from another question, but not getting any luck.

i have a dynamic textboxes and want to apply some autocomplete on it, here's my code

Javascript :

```
 $(function () {
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents p').size();

$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $(' <tr> <td> <input type="text" id="kdbr" class ="kdbr" style="width:300px;" name="kdbr[]" value=""/></td><td> <input type="text" id="nmbr" class ="nmbr" style="width:300px;" name="nmbr[]" value=""  /></td><td><input type="text" id="jumlah" style="width:80px;" name="jumlah[]" value=""  /></td></label> <td><input id="remScnt" style="width:80px;" class="btn" type="button" value="Remove" ></td> </tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    //if (i > 1) {
        $(this).parents('tbody').remove();
      //  i--;
    //}
    return false;
});

$(".kdbr").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>js/coba3.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
            //  var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                response($.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        value: el.kdbr,
                        label: el.nmbr
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        // Prevent value from being put in the input:
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.kdbr').val(ui.item.value);
        // Set the next input's value to the "value" of the item.
        $('.nmbr').val(ui.item.label);

    }

});
});
```

html :

```
<table id="p_scents" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:400px;">Kode Barang</th>
        <th style="width:400px;">Nama Barang</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Jumlah</th>
        <th style="width:100px;">Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 

<label for="p_scnts"> 
<tr><td> <input type="text" id="kdbr" class ="kdbr" style="width:300px;" name="kdbr[]" value=""  /></td><td> <input type="text" id="nmbr" class ="nmbr" style="width:300px;" name="nmbr[]" value=""  /></td><td><input type="text" id="jumlah" style="width:80px;" name="jumlah[]" value=""  /></td></label> <td><input id="remScnt" style="width:80px;" class="btn" type="button" value="Remove" ></td></tr>

</tbody>
```

the autocomplete only works on first row that not being dynamic and everytime i tried to point my mouse into the autocomplete list or try to point down, the list will dissapear immediately.

can someone please tell me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead.
- for dynamically added elements use

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function() {});
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  $('.remScnt').on('click', function() {});
  ```
- you had incorrect html structure due to `label` mixed with `tr`
- for dymanically added elements `autocomplete` should be called (to handle this autocomplete settings should be made global).
- function to delete row was incorrect.
- autocomplete `select` event handler was incorrect: it added selected value to all rows.
- autocomplete `source` function was replaced with array only for tests.

[Fiddle with this](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/0o8jwzed/).

```
var autoCompleteSettings =
{
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ],
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        // Prevent value from being put in the input:
        event.preventDefault();
        var selectedEl = $(event.target);
        selectedEl.val(ui.item.value);
        // Set the next input's value to the "value" of the item.
       selectedEl.closest('td').next().find('input').val(ui.item.label);
    }
};

var addId = 0;

$(function()
{
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function()
    {
        addId++;
        $('<tr> <td> <input type="text" id="kdbr' + addId + '" class ="kdbr" style="width:300px;" name="kdbr[]" value=""/></td><td> <input type="text" class ="nmbr" style="width:300px;" name="nmbr[]" value=""  /></td><td><input type="text" style="width:80px;" name="jumlah[]" value="" /></td><td><input class="remScnt btn" type="button" value="Remove" ></td> </tr>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        $('#kdbr' + addId).autocomplete(autoCompleteSettings);
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function()
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });

    $(".kdbr").autocomplete(autoCompleteSettings);
});
```

Comment: i follow your lead and get the list for each field, but still everytime i tried to point my mouse or press down button, the autocomplete suggestion list will be dissapear..

Comment: @ryuusoultaker does it disappear in fiddle or on your site? If in fiddle - what browser do you use?

Comment: i've found the reason why the list dissapear, because i accidently declare the js file twice..and then your code works like magic :) i've mark it as accepted  answer :)